# Integration of $x$ with respect to $\left [ x \right ]$

Tags: integration

I want find the integration of $x$ with respect to $\left [ x \right ]$.
There is no limit.

I have a confusion. As $\left [ x \right ]$ is discontinuos, how can we integrate?
Please help.

Comment: This is a Stieltjes integral. Read up on those sorts of things.

Comment: Can you list out the specific integral?  Is it $\int x\text d[x]$?

Comment: what is [x]? also to find with respect to another function just use chain rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: user29418, [x] is box of x, which implies the integral part of x.

Comment: @user29418 , but here no limit is given

Comment: @abiessu , yes, it is

Answer (score 3):

Note that
\begin{align}
\int^{n+1}_n f(x)\ d[x] = f(n+1)
\end{align}
then we see that
\begin{align}
\int^b_a f(x)\ d[x] =  \sum_{i=[a]+1}^{[b]} f(i). 
\end{align}

In particular, we see that
\begin{align}
\int^b_a x\ d[x] = \sum_{i=[a]+1}^{[b]} i = \frac{([b]+1)[b]}{2}-\frac{([a]+1)[a]}{2}.
\end{align}

Comment: But there is no limit

Comment: Well. $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary.

Comment: But it is indefinite integration.. a and b are not defined

Comment: What do you think the indefinite integral means? Antiderivative?